# Get count of a column based on join from other table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am new to SQL. I have to tables and trying to get the count of column from table 1 and join by other column in table 2.

Table 1:

```
credits | sec_code | student_acc_id
--------------------------------
4            TUB        2098
5            JIY        2099
6            THG        3011
```

Table 2:

```
id| sec_code | student_acc_id | stu_id
-------------------------------------
1      TUB        2098          1011
5      JIY        2099          1011
7      THG        3011          1012
```

I would like to get the sum of credits for the student by getting the stu_id from table2 from sec_code and get all the student_acc_id for stuId and sum the credits column in table1 for all the student account Ids found from table 2. I am not sure how can we join or make this query simple.

Normally my approach is to inlcude this two to three different SQL statements, but i am looking for this in a one sql query if possible.

For the above example lets say i want to get sum of credits for all student_acc_id  where stu_id is 1011 from second table. i just have the first table. So the output should be 4+5 as both accounts belong to the same student.

So i need:
--> get the stu_id based on sec_code from table two (lets say for TUB sec_code)
--> get all student_acc_id from table where stu_id is result from above statement
-->now using those all student_acc_id's sum the credit in table 1

Any help is appreciated !

Comment: Hint:  `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Inner Join just gives the common elements. But my requirement is a bit different here.So from table one using sec_code or student_acc_id get all student_acc_id from table 2 where the stu_id and calculate the sum of credits for those accounts from table 1.

Comment: @Stackmeup: Please post sample output layout

Comment: @irfan_m added the code

Comment: @irfan_m i have added steps as well

Comment: @Stackmeup: Please check below solution on fiddle also.

Answer (score 0):

try like below

```
  select t2.stu_id, 
  sum(t1.credits) 
  from t1 join t2 on t1.student_acc_id=t2.student_acc_id and
  t1.sec_code=t2.sec_code
  group by stu_id
  Having count(stu_id)>1
```

Comment: groupBy will give all the results which i dont want as well right? I just want the result of matching stu_id. but group will give all others in the result as well :(

Answer (score 0):

Use Join according to your Data exist.
But as per the sample data better to get Data from Right table.

---

```
select
    tab2.stud_id,
    SUM(tab1.credits) AS credit_sum
from
    table1 as tab1
    right join
        table2 as tab2
    on  tab1.student_acc_id = tab2.student_acc_id
    and tab1.sec_cd = tab2.sec_cd
where
    tab2.stud_id in(
        select distinct stud_id
        from table2
        where student_acc_id = '2098'
    )
group by
    tab2.stud_id;
```

You can check its sample output here. Please [click](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/11689/7) for fiddle solution.

Comment: @Stakemeup : If there has possibility of having 'Credit' column as NULL then Please use ISNULL(credit,0) for the safety.

Comment: but groupBy will give all the stu_id results. but i am interested to get only one stu_is results lets say in the above example just search by student_acc_id 2098 and the expected result should be just 9

Comment: @Stackmeup: Please refer WHERE condition for that. I have already added in to code. just remove /*COMMENTS*/